# Showing that the product of conjugates in the Galois groups of a extension is the minimal polynomial.

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

I try showing the following exercise:

> Let $K/F$ Galois extension of field. Suppose that $\alpha$ is algebraic over $K$ (but not necessarily contained in $K$) and that $G:=\text{Gal}({K/F})$. Let $f:=\text{Irr}_{K,\alpha}$ be the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $K$. Show that the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $F$ is
> $$\text{Irr}_{F,\alpha}=\prod_{\overline{\sigma}\in G/G_f} \sigma(f)$$
> where $\sigma(f)(x)\in K[x]$ is the conjugate of
> $f,\ G:=\text{Gal}(K/F)$ and  $G_f:=\text{stab}_{G}(f)$.

Next I put my solution omitting calculation details. In this I have doubts in the final part. I would like to see if what I am doing is correct.

Because $\alpha$ is root of $\text{Irr}_{F,\alpha}$ and $F\subset K$ subfield then $f\mid \text{Irr}_{F,\alpha}$ in $K[x]$.

Let $\sigma\in G$ then $\sigma(f)\mid \sigma(\text{Irr}_{F,\alpha})$ and $\sigma(\text{Irr}_{F,\alpha})=\text{Irr}_{F,\alpha}$ because the coefficients are in $F$.  $\sigma(f)$ is monic irreducible because $f$ is monic irreducible and $\sigma$ is $\mathbb{F}$-automorphism.

Analogously, if $\sigma'\in G: \sigma'\neq \sigma$ then $\sigma'(f)$ is monic irreducible.

Therefore, $\sigma$ and $\sigma'$ are coprimes.

Therefore  $\prod_{\sigma\in G} \sigma(f)\mid \text{Irr}_{F,\alpha}$

Now, if $\tau\in G$ then
$$\tau \prod_{\sigma\in G}\sigma(f)=\prod_{\sigma \in G}\tau\sigma(f)=\prod_{\sigma \in G}\sigma(f)$$
therefore the coefficients of $\prod_{\sigma \in G}\sigma(f)$ are in $F$. Therefore $\text{Irr}_{F,\alpha}=\prod_{\sigma\in G} \sigma(f)$

Now, (in this part is my doubt) let $\phi:G\to G/G_f$ given by $\phi(\sigma)=\sigma G_f=:\overline{\sigma}$. Then $\phi$ is bijective.

therefore $\prod_{\sigma\in G} \sigma(f)=\prod_{\overline{\sigma}\in G/G_f}\sigma(f)$.

The last part is correct?
Thanks

**Actualization 1.** Now I did it!

Let $\overline{\sigma},\overline{\sigma'}$ distints then $\sigma(f)$ and $\sigma'(f)$ coprimes because $\sigma(f)\neq \sigma'(f)$ and are irreducibles and monic. (If $\sigma(f)=\sigma'(f)$ then $\sigma{\sigma'}^{-1}(f)=f$ i.e. $\overline{\sigma}=\overline{\sigma'})$

and then what follows is the same as my post concluding that
$\text{Irr}_{F,\alpha}=\prod_{\overline{\sigma}\in G/G_f}f_\sigma.$

Comment: Do you mean $\alpha$ is algebraic over $K$ and not necessarily in $K$? Your $\mathrm{Irr}_{K,\alpha}$ notation means minimal polynomial? Your claim that $G \to G/G_f$ is bijective implies that always $G_f=1$, but if $\alpha$ is in $K$ and not in $F$, then $f = \mathrm{Irr}_{K,\alpha}$ is linear and fixed by all automorphisms, that fix $\alpha$, this group is in general not trivial.

Comment: Yes. Is the minimal polynomial over $K$. I do not know if $\alpha$ is in $K$.

Comment: Ok, you should first try to understand why $G_f$ is not always trivial. If you consider the orbit $\{\sigma(f) \mid \sigma \in G\}$ under $G$, then $f$ (and every other element) is stabilized by $G_f$. And $\prod_{\sigma \in G} \sigma(f)$ is a power of $\prod_{\sigma \in G/G_f} \sigma(f)$.

Comment: I see. Then I fix mi proof in the last part...

Comment: I still my doubt. The function $\phi:G\to G/G_f$ given by $\phi(\sigma)=\sigma G_f$ is bijective.

The injectivity because if $\phi(\sigma))=G_f$ then $\sigma\in G_f$ then $\sigma(f)=f$ then $\sigma(\text{coefficients of } f)=\text{coefficients of } f$
then $\sigma=Id$ is injective. The epijectivity is inmediately.

Now, (this is my doubt) $\prod_{\overline{\sigma}\in G/G_f}=\prod_{\sigma\in G}$?

Comment: If $\sigma$ fixes the coefficients of $f$, then why is $\sigma$ the identity? We only know, that $\sigma$ is the identity on the subfield of $K$ generated by the coefficients of $f$.

Comment: oh right! I need add $\sigma(f(\alpha))=f(\alpha)$ then $\sigma(\alpha)=\alpha$ then $\sigma=Id$
this is correct?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. $f(\alpha) = 0$ since $f$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$. It is still not true in general, that $\sigma = \mathrm{id}$ when $\sigma(f) = f$. Every $\sigma \in G_f$ produces a copy of $f$ in $\prod_{\sigma \in G} \sigma(f)$. We have to get rid of these copies in order to make the product irreducible. Thats why we range over $G/G_f$.

Comment: I see. I need proves that $\prod_{\overline{\sigma}\in G/G_f}\sigma(f)=\prod_{\sigma\in G}\sigma(f)$ For this I think it is necessary to consider the case with $G_f=\left\{Id\right\}$ and $G_f\neq \left\{Id\right\}$ but i am lost.

Comment: The equality is not true. We have $(\prod_{\bar \sigma \in G/G_f} \sigma(f))^k = \prod_{\sigma \in G} \sigma(f)$, where $k = |G_f|$. You can start with $k=1$ of course.

Comment: Why not the same? being that $\text{Irr}_{F,\alpha} =\prod_{\sigma\in G}\sigma(f)$, and if I could prove that $\text{Irr}_{F,\alpha} =\prod_{\overline{\sigma}\in G/G_f}\sigma(f)$ then if they would be equal because $\prod_{\sigma\in G}\sigma(f)=\prod_{\overline{\sigma}\in G/G_f}\sigma(f) $ I am lost...

Comment: Why does that last equality hold? They don't have the same degree.